# Debian Wheezy drivers for HP ProLiant DL360 Gen9 RAID controller

Tags: linux, debian, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I bought 2 HP DL360 Gen9 Servers and wanted install Debian Wheezy on those with PXE Boot network install. But it seems that Wheezy does not include a driver for the Smart Array Controllter `p440ar/2g`. The installer asks me if I want to continue without a hard drive. I already tried to install Debian Jessie and it works without a problem, but i currently still need Wheezy for my Xen cluster.

Is there a way to install Wheezy?

Answer (score 0):

Debian isn't [officially supported](http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=7252838&swLangOid=8&swEnvOid=4155) on this hardware. You'll be missing some value-add features like monitoring agents and having an easy process for installation.

People have found *janky* workarounds, though.

See: https://wiki.debian.org/HP/ProLiant 
and https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2015/04/msg00028.html

Also: http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/ProLiant-Servers-ML-DL-SL/Install-Debian-7-on-HP-DL360-Gen9/td-p/6733883#.Vc3MfHjDvSw

Comment: Shouldn't the regular HP monitoring and maintenance tools at http://downloads.linux.hp.com/SDR/downloads/MCP/debian/pool/non-free/ (`deb http://downloads.linux.hp.com/SDR/repo/mcp/debian wheezy/current non-free`) work for this? There are still clearly some driver issues during the installation that need to be overcome, though,

Comment: If the damn installer doesn't work, and the OS isn't providing a current storage driver, and the manufacturer isn't providing a driver to slipstream during installation, it's a sign that the OS/distribution isn't the best choice for this hardware platform.

Comment: true, i want to update to jessie but no yet. this is just supposed to be temporal